# If a Wildfire druid uses the Enhanced Bond feature to cast a concentration spell through their spirit, who maintains concentration on the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, druid, concentration

The [Circle of Wildfire druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleofWildfire) gains the Enhanced Bond feature at 6th level. The feature description states, in part (TCoE, p. 39):

> In addition, when you cast a spell with a range other than self, the spell can originate from you or your wildfire spirit.

If you cast a spell that requires concentration through your spirit, are you concentrating, or does the spirit do so?

Comment: Related: "[Can your familiar concentrate on a spell it delivers?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103617)"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 19):

#### You cast the spell, so you’re concentrating.

The [Wildfire druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleofWildfire)'s Enhanced Bond feature says:

> [...] when **you** cast the spell [...]

So if the spell requires concentration, you must concentrate. Enhanced Bond doesn’t say anything about concentrating on spells, so it doesn’t change anything about concentrating on spells. The word “originate” is referring only to the space the spell originates from (i.e. the point of origin of the spell, from which its range is measured) – either yours or your spirit’s.